# Comparing how good models with binary dependent variable are

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, least-squares, logit

So I'm not very well versed when it comes to statistics, so this is a bit over my head.

I can't go into too much detail (NDA, etc etc), but I have four different datasets where in every dataset there are a number of people who make predictions (binary) about different parts the economy (think something like a Purchasing Managers Index). In the first dataset it could be something like "In one year, will this company stock be up or down). In the second it could be "In one year will the GDP in Germany increase or decrease".

Within each dataset, the ones making the predictions are indexed by a number, but this index is not comparable across datasets.

Now, I would like to see if some questions are easier or harder to answer. Since all questions actually have an outcome at one point, I have data for the actual outcome of previous predictions.

How do I go about doing this? I tried looking at logit, but I'm not sure how I would interpret the results. Can I use regular OLS? If I use OLS, the actual predictions by the model might be outside the (0, 1) range, which feels a bit "problematic".

Any help/pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To use logistic regression your response needs to be binary, or binary counts. So it depends on how your response was collected. If your response is not binary then by all means use OLS. Interpreting logistic regression can be tricky but I find if you just exponentiate the coefficient then you are working with odds. If you do a google search there are a lot of good examples of interpreting logistic regression. Also The Statistical Sleuth in chps 20-21 does a good job explaining logistic regression.